# What is a person who works on applying makeup called?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've read 'Makeup technician' in some places, but I am looking for a single word.

'Aesthetician' and 'Cosmetologist' refer to persons who apply general aesthetic treatments, but I haven't found any words which refer specifically and exclusively to applying makeup.

Comment: Regardless, legally, in the state of Maine, the person is called a ***cosmetologist***, or with lesser experience ***esthetician***: http://www.beautyschoolsdirectory.com/faq/license_me.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Visagiste](http://useful_english.enacademic.com/463630/visagist)** An expert in facial make up.  [Kevyn Aucoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevyn_Aucoin) called himself a make-up artist

Answer (score 8):

Makeup is today recognized as an evolved form of art, aesthetics and technology.

***[makeup artist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make-up_artist)***

A make-up artist (or 'makeup artist') is an artist whose medium is the human body, applying makeup and prosthetics for theatrical, television, film, fashion, magazines and other similar productions including all aspects of the modeling industry.

Also referred to as: *makeup designer, makeup creator, makeup technician, creative makeup designer*

Comment: While this is the phrase that sprang to my mind when I read the question, the OP did mention they were looking for a single word.

Comment: @MrLister - that begs the question if a word cannot contain spaces. I cannot think of good reasons why Kris' answer would have been acceptable if English had followed Dutch _spelling_ rules and _written_ it "makeupartist", but for one (or two) spaces the word is not a word any more?.

Comment: @oerkelens Or the German way of *makeupartist* or the camelCase style of *makeupArtist* for that matter. Well, however, in English a space is indeed a delimiter as of today.

Comment: @Kris - I guess it's more of a meta discussion indeed whether a concept like _ice cream_ would qualify as an answer for a single-word request when someone is looking for something cold, usually sweet and edible.

Comment: There's a *terminology* tag that I had been interested in but rarely ever come by on ELU. I think the OP could use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Beautician** is the correct word to describe the person whose profession is to increase appearance of the lady or gentleman  by putting make ups and giving different treatments to body.. "

**Make up artist** is one who works in movie industry or drama industry whose main job is not only putting make up on actors to    increase their appearance but also putting different make ups according to role of the persons and situations of the movie.

**Beautician**, from the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/16675?redirectedFrom=beautician#eid)

> A person who provides professional services to improve the appearance
>   of the face, body, or hair; a person who works in a beauty salon; (now
>   also) the salon itself

**Makeup Artist**, from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make-up_artist)

> A make-up artist or makeup artist is an artist whose medium is the
>   human body, applying makeup and prosthetics for theatrical,
>   television, filmmaking, fashion, magazines and other similar
>   productions including all aspects of the modeling industry

Comment: A 'beautician' works almost exclusively on hair. I can't imagine them working on make-up

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You should provide evidence in support of your answer, rather than merely stating it. For additional guidance on writing good answers that meet our community standards, I direct you to the site [tour] and [help].

Comment: Added definitions and links to your answer.  The site requires more than personal knowledge in its answers.

Answer (score -1):

A person in such an occupation is called a *farder*. (Look up the verb *fard*.)

Comment: Dictionaries say *fard* is **archaic** today. *Farder* on the other hand seems to be an "obsolete variant of *farther*."

Comment: If it is archaic, then how did it achieve that status, inasmuch as women have been employing makeup for millennia? Without an adequate replacement, why would a useful word suddenly become useless?

Comment: Well, then, how about "upmaker?" Yes, my tongue is well thrust into my cheek.

Comment: Some words survive, some don't.